# How to order a parse query case insensitive on iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I run a simple parse query on iOS:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Channel")
query.order(byAscending: "name")
```

It does order the results correctly by name. However it does order by `a` after `Z`. For example it returns:

- Album
- Tree
- Zoo
- always
- yellow

**This is not the order I do expect**. I would like to see it ignore the case of the letters. How can I do that?

Comment: This is because the ASCII table order of these letters (The small letter come after the capital ones.). You can either store everything in lowercase / uppercase when inserting, so the final comparison is in the same case of letters, or, you can filter the results to convert them in the same case when you retrieve, and then run this ordering.

Comment: I can not do sorting on the client as the response is paginated.

Comment: Then just run a .map through the results and convert all names to lowercase/uppercase before applying the .order function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I guess you are not familiar with the Parse SDK. I have to create the query (including order) on the client and send it to the server. Then the server does all the processing.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a function to do this through Parse directly.  Your best bet, if case sensitivity isn't an issue, is to add a beforeSave trigger for this class, and cast all the input for the fields you're querying over to lowercase / uppercase. This will solve your issue, as long as the field is not otherwise case-sensitive in your functionality.

A background job with a query.each() over this class to update everything should also be fairly simple to get the DB up to date with the new lowercase/uppercase requirements.